# Can you Create a Native Vue App with NuxtJS

Tags: vuejs2, nuxt.js, vue-native

Nuxt is great and I understand clearly the problems it solves.

Where one desires a Nuxt-based SPA as well as native ios/ android versions, does it mean that you have to deal with 2 different code bases and no way to package the resulting SPA as a Vue Native app?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Nativescript-vue](https://nativescript.org/vue/) if you want to work in similar manner as in Nuxt.js.

And if your web app is built in vue, then you can share your code for mobile and web apps simultaneously https://nativescript-vue.org/en/docs/getting-started/code-sharing/

Answer (score 0):

I came across the nice article that compares the native options in the Vue ecosystem, which could help you if you are looking for a similar framework: [Vue mobile development Frameworks](https://blog.logrocket.com/comparing-vue-js-mobile-app-development-frameworks/#ionicvue), [Mobile Apps with Vue](https://vue-community.org/guide/ecosystem/mobile-apps.html#summary-tldr)

Alternatively, if you are keen in using Nuxt but limited to android this will help you [Android App from Nuxt](https://blog.logrocket.com/how-to-build-a-twa-android-app-out-of-your-nuxt-js-pwa/)

Comment: Lol, thanks. I now look at Flutter when I want close to native and Nuxt PWA when that's not so key.